# Spring Security Grails get user details when logging in

Tags: grails, spring-security

I am trying to get more details when I log into my Grails application using Spring Security.

For e.g.:

When I log in using :

```
http://localhost:8080/XXX/auth/login
```

I get authentication success and below is the sample response.

```
{"username":"lalit","roles":["XXX"],"access_token":"something"}
```

Instead of this, I would also like to return some more user related data like full name.

```
{"username":"lalit","roles":["XXX"],"access_token":"something","fname":"Lalit Agarwal"}
```

So, you could see full name also returned as response when I log in.

Note: I have already added a custom field fullName using this : http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/userDetailsService.html

Answer (score 0):

The [link](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/userDetailsService.html) you noted pretty much outlines exactly what you need to do. You should extend the `GormUserDetailsService` (or write your own and make sure it implements `GrailsUserDetailsService`) to make sure that when `loadUserByUsername` is called, it add the full name to the returned object. Then you just need to add the new bean to your `resources.groovy` file under the name `userDetailsService`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I forgot to mention in the question that I was authenticating using spring security rest plugin and was able to sort it out using the spring security rest plugin docs.

Comment: Can you provide the solution please?